# Init App from SQLite DB from multiple table?

Tags: android, list, android-asynctask

In my app,

First Screen is splash screen, it displays the `ProgressDialog` until the data is loaded from DB and then forward the user to next Main App Screen.

I am using `doInBackground` to load category data and in `onPostExecute` set this to catgoryList.

I also want to laod some category `Item's` when app inits.

1) Is is fine to execute two AsyncTasks, one for category and other for items.

2) Or can it be done in one `AsyncTask`. `doInBackground` can return only one type of list at the moment.

How can I change it to return both `catgory` and `item` from `doInBackground` of one `AsyncTask`.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is is fine to execute two AsyncTasks, one for category and other for items.

Yes, this is fine.

In order to synchronize with your main activity, you have at least two solutions:

1. Run the AsyncTasks sequentially. The first AsyncTask will spawn a second one in its `onPostExecute()`. Then the second task starts the main activity.
2. Use a countdown latch. Conceptually this is just a integer that is incremented by each AsyncTask as it completes. Java and Android implement this idea in [`CountDownLatch`](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/CountDownLatch.html). When the count down is reached, then you can start the main activity. [This YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OeBvP_ygiWE) gives a great in-depth description of the concepts involved.

Comment: One more thing, how to know when both `AsyncTask` have been executed, can I use a static counter and increment it on start and `onPostExecute ` check if the counter is zero again to move to next activity i.e the main screen for user ?

Comment: @user3141985 One potential solution is to run the `AsyncTask`s sequentially, rather than in parallel. To do this, the first `AsyncTask` will start the second in its `onPostExecute()`. Then the second task will start the main screen activity.

Comment: I know my data is not that large, but what is better, to run the two AsyncTasks sequentially, or parallel ?

Comment: @user3141985 It depends. You should measure the performance between the two implementations which I suggest in my edit. A sequential implementation is much simpler to write. On the other hand a parallel implementation may perform better, depending on the number of physical cores/threads which are available.

Answer (score 1):

> How can I change it to return both catgory and item from doInBackground of one AsyncTask.

Store them in a list and return it in doInBackground.
You can get it by identify the position.

Comment: you mean to store each list of category and items in a new list and return that new list ? That sound really nice !!!

Answer (score 1):

You can also define a new type as value holder and use it:

```
public class DataValueHolder {
    public List<Item> items;
    public List<Category> categories;
}
```

Now, create an object of this class and return it in doInBackground method.